# Add to cart button is not working Open cart

Tags: php, opencart

Just I have kept open cart Add to cart button inside bootstrap model and I'm trying to add product into the cart but button is not working

Comment: Have seen you here some time ago. I suggest you to make your questions bigger, with better describing of the issue (Opencart version, specific page, code examples etc.). And after you receiving a valuable answer - don' forget to **mark** it as **accepted** (only if it's helped you to solve a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on version, but. In OpenCart 3 (in 2,3 quite similar), add-to-cart bottons work like:

On the every product list buttons should be like this: `<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('43');">...</button>`. The part `onclick="cart.add('ID');` is most valuable. It connects the object `cart` and let script in **common.js** to process adding to a cart. Do not remove it in any case.

If we are talking about **product page** - there is a construction like this:

```
<div id="product">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity">Qty</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="43" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this area we should keep all elements `id`, `type` and `name` untouched. All inside `<div id="product">` helps to process adding product to a cart, all of them take part in script processing and if you will change anything i mentioned - the script will stop working properly. You are free to change order of the tags and their classes, according to bootstrap or your own. If you have already modified this block and it stops working - just restore it from a clear default OpenCart version (or your theme).